# Is there a way to change the color wheel used in the node editor?

Tags: node-editor, color-management

I really dislike the color wheel for picking certain colors, especially browns. I would really like a few [more options](http://www.google.com/search?q=color+selection&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=LyS&rls=org.mozilla:nl:official&channel=sb&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=vtkGVMfKBqTy7AbZ2YHgDQ&ved=0CEYQsAQ&biw=1920&bih=983) to pick the colors. A large amount of swatches would be especially nice. Now I often go to a [site listing color codes](http://cloford.com/resources/colours/500col.htm) and copy paste these into Blender, which is a laborious process.

Comment: For brown, just go to red and reduce the value(slider on the right). If you can come up with a way that allows full control over the hue, saturation and value in an intuitive way, let me know, 'cause even Photoshop failed at that...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can choose from four different [color picker types](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Interface/Buttons_and_Controls) in the [user preferences](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Preferences/System):

[image]

Perhaps you like one the options better:

[image]

You might be also interested in the [Palette addon](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Paint/Palettes) which only works only in paint modes (Image Painting, Texture Paint, Vertex Paint, Weight Paint)